# Chrome not loading HTML file properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am learning to build a web application using a Lynda tutorial. They have provided a sample application, which in their tutorial looks like this when loaded into Safari:
[image: properly functioning app]

but when I try to open the same html file it shows up like this: (the only browser option is chrome, because it says it is a Chrome HTML

[image: what the app looks like in my Chrome browser]

I am very new to web development, and I am not sure what could be causing this problem. I already disabled my AdBlock. I am using Windows 10 but the tutorial is using a Mac.

Thank you!!

Comment: You are missing css and maybe other files as well.

Comment: Please post the code you have. As others have said, you're probably missing the CSS. You're either doing something wrong with linking to them or not linking at all.

Comment: when you open file in chrome just right click and choose inspect look for any error there

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Stylesheets aren't loading, make sure you have linked the right files in your `head`'s `link` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your stylesheets are linked correctly. Learn the difference between relative and absolute links.

Ad Block won't affect anything, and your OS wouldn't have this much of an impact on the site not loading correctly. Posting your code generally helps us out a ton! At the very least, would you mind posting your stylesheet links, so that we could help you get those right?

Answer (score 0):

currently, I'm facing the same problem. here the quick solution, use Microsoft Visual Studio code editor and install a plugin called "Live Server".

what I'm facing is if I open Html file using "live server" it is working, if I directly opening in the browser it is not loading the CSS properly.